# vscode import extra environment path in python when execute in interactive window, how to avoid this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm a beginner for vscode and python. Today, I try to use `sys.path.append` to add a new python environment path so I can import one of my private modular, but I find there are some environment path already exists in the `sys.path` list (see the path in the red rectangle in the attached picture). Some of those path belone to my other projects, and they are conflict with the target modular. But when I open `Ipyhon` in Terminal and print the `sys.path`, the path in the red rectangle is not listed again. What did vscode do so the extra environment path was included? How can I avoid those paths are imported?

[image]

Comment: What specific impact does this have on your running code or use? According to the information you provide, you are executing in "Interactive", which uses the related services and functions provided by the "Jupyter" extension.

Comment: I'd like to import a script named as path_config.py, which located in the parent directory of the current running script (the parent directory of the first path in the picture). While there is a script with the same name (path_config.py) in my other project (the second path in the picture).

Comment: When I try to import the target path_config.py file by typing `sys.path.append("..")` and `from path_config import *`, the program always import the file from the second path. I'm now handle this by removing the second path using `sys.path.remove('the second path')` to make sure the script work, but it doesn't solve the root of the problem. So I'd like to know if there are better method to deal with this.

Comment: Have you tried to test this process in different terminals? What is the result of the terminal test outside VS Code?

Comment: Yes. In the terminal, the `sys.path` list don't include the environment path in the red rectangle in the picture, and works well.

Comment: Just did more test. The second path is the path of the first folder in the workspace (I add three root folder in the workspace). If I change other folder on the top location, the second path in the picuture will be changed too. Just don't know how to avoid this, because each of root folder including a path_config.py file ; (